# confusing console and file output when using system() function

Tags: c, file-io, system

I have the following code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //freopen("file1","w",stdout);
    char str[]="command line with file";
    char s[]="extra string";
    puts(str);
    puts(s);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

when I see the output on console it shows me,

```
command line with file
extra string
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And I expect same output when writing output into a file by removing the commented line in code. But it outputs like,

```
Press any key to continue . . . 
command line with file
extra string
```

why this distinction between file and console output??? 
here system("PAUSE") function is responsible for the string output `Press any key to continue . . .`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing to a terminal, `stdout` is line-buffered. It writes each line immediately. When writing to a file, it's block-buffered. It stores a few kilobytes in a buffer and flushes them out when you call `fflush`, or when the buffer is full, or when the program ends. The pause message is being written by a separate process which exits before your original process, at which point it must flush its buffer (if it has one). Then your original process's `system()` ends and it reaches the end of `main()` and exits, flushing the buffer containing your two test strings.

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: line-buffered and block-buffered you have cited..I asked if there any other type of buffering exist with `stdout`. another thing is, if now i want to output in file like in console in my given code, is a preceding `fflush` of `system("PAUSE")` enough? what buffer I should flush in that case with `fflush` ???

Comment: oh I got that. I have to `fflush` the buffer `stdout`...thank you

Comment: There are 3 kinds: block buffer, line buffer, and no buffer. You can manually choose the buffer type (and the size of the block buffer) with the functions `setbuf` and `setvbuf`